# Grub does not display on older computer

Tags: server, grub2, display

I'm trying to install ubuntu server 12.04 on an older desktop for a friend. The tower doesnt have an onboard graphics card, so we had to install an AGP graphics card to plug in a monitor. The install all displayed correctly, but after completing, the monitor switched to "No Signal". I was able to boot into Ubuntu initially by pressing enter on this invisible screen, and the OS seemed to display correctly.

I tried holding down SHIFT, after modifying /etc/default/grub to have a timeout, to no avail.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `GRUB_GXMODE` to `640x480x16` in `/etc/default/grub`:
`GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480x16`

Next, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I have seen this fixed by setting console mode. If the OP has trouble with this, my method could be useful.

Comment: Awesome, I did both of these and it works perfectly now. Thanks for the help!